# dataframe rows in R have to be unique?

Tags: r, dataframe

I haven't seen this before in R, but in the book 'Advanced Analytics in Power BI with R and Python', the author says:
[image]

Why do they have to be unique? how is it enforced?

Comment: There is not that restriction. I think that his point it that in order to create a "visual" (which i don't know what it is, so i might be wrong) you need a data frame with unique rows (you have to make sure of that by yourself), not that every data frame needs that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This applies to the very specific combination of R and Powerbi (when you run R from within Powerbi), when you open the R code viewer in Powerbi you will see the following:

```
# Create dataframe
dataset <- data.frame(...) 

# Remove duplicated rows
dataset <- unique(dataset)
```

The above part cannot be modified! If you want to use all rows as they are, you have to include a unique identifier (i.e. a primary key) for the dataset, even if you don't have any other particular use for it as part of the visual.

For reference see [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-r-visuals), section "Create R visuals in Power BI Desktop", paragraph 4